# Javascript not applying to page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have 4 sets of Promoted Links in a table. The idea being the top set show one of the others depending on which tile is clicked.

I have slightly modified [THIS SCRIPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26522.everything-about-promoted-links-in-sharepoint-2013-change-size-wrap-view-handle-click-event-using-jquery.aspx#How_to_handle_click_event_of_a_promoted_link_tile) to match my needs, but nothing happens.

I have inserted the below into a Script Editor webpart. What am I missing?

EDIT - line 10 - 13 are bothering me...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/JQuery/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
$("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
$("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();
});
    $(function () {
    $("a[id^=Tile_WPQ]").each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var linkTitle = $(this).find('li[title]').attr('id');
                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_1_7")
                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").show();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();
                    event.returnValue = false;

                }

                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_2_7")

                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").show();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }

                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_3_7")

                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").show();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are the minimal download strategy feature activated on the site?

Comment: Make sure the JQuery is loaded in the page. You can also check the console logs for any error

Comment: Im getting somewhere... part of the proplem was the wrong tile ID (doh!!) Now when i click, the relevant promoted links show exacly where you would expect to but then go straight off the the Promoted Links page. It's almost as if i need to over-ride the launch behavouir or something but the promoted links require this to be sut up!

Comment: SORTED. All this was, was the Promoted Links launch behaviour needing to be set to "New Tab" - no new tab is actually launched so fits my bill a treat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example from one of my scripts:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideWP");
function HideWP()   
    {   
        //Function body 
    }
```

"HideWP" being a wrapping function for the rest of the script..

Try this....

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("pageLoad");
  function pageLoad(sender, args)   
    {     
      $("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
      $("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
      $("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();

      $(function () {
      $("a[id^=Tile_WPQ]").each(function () {
            $(this).click(function () {
                var linkTitle = $(this).find('li[title]').attr('id');
                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_1_7")
                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").show();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();
                    event.returnValue = false;

                }

                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_2_7")

                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").show();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").hide();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }

                if (linkTitle == "Tile_WPQ2_3_7")

                {
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ3").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ4").hide();
                    $("div#WebPartWPQ5").show();
                    event.returnValue = false;
                }
          });
        });
      });
    } // End pageLoad  
</script>
```

Also note that the following would work too, replace
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("pageLoad");
with
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(pageLoad, "sp.js");

Comment: at least 2 people agree with this, only i don't know enough about js to where exactly to insert this line and/or what else to remove from my original script! Help please :-)

Comment: Great, thanks. I had to tweak it a little (tile IDs mainly) and it sort of works.  When I click the top Promoted link, for a split second the lower one displays (as expected) but the opens up the lower Promoted Links in a seperate page. How do i modify this behaviour?  All your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t use jquery´s`( document).ready` function in SharePoint. Use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` or something like that. Because the Rendering of SharePoint-Contents happens most using Javascript also **AFTER** Body loaded, so in your case, even if `document.ready` fired adequately, the desired Objects in the dom may not have been rendered already

Finally, as I don´t know how your html is built of, I can´t help you any further.

But hopefully you included the jquery-file in the correct Folder of your SharePoint-Server.

Comment: it would maybe help if you make an example of how to use  _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames

Comment: _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("<NameofyourFunction>"). This ensures the execution of the Function with that Name after SharePoint has loaded and rendered completely.

Comment: so replace "$(document).ready(function()" with "_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames"?  excluding the " "

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue before.
You can use:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Your Javascript here
});
```

It seems that the page is ready before SharePoint load or render all the "SharePoint elements" inside.

Comment: Still no action..

Comment: Can you use the debugger? In Chrome press f12 and click on the console tab just to check if you have errors in the js

Comment: Great idea! The debugger says "SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined" and points at line 620, which is    $(window).load(finctioon() {

Comment: adding this to the top  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
  now hides the bottom three promoted links, as i was hoping but clicking on the top row only opens them in a new page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
function init(){
    // JavaScript code here
}
```

Comment: adding that then made all promoted links visible, as if no conde was applied to the page.

Comment: Do you have `originalid` as one of the attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete template I use when adding script to my webpages, granted I am throwing this in a CEWP and pointing to the script that way. I don't inject my code into the page itself. Hopefully you can glean something from this....

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="MyFormDigest" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(pageLoad, "sp.js");
  function pageLoad(sender, args)   
    {      // Wrapping function
    } // End wrapping 
</script>
```